# Multiple threads accessing multiple objects

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a GUI window with four text boxes, and my code allows for the user to create multiple threads. I want that for each thread, the thread finds an available text area and completes its output statements. I have managed to get only one thread to execute at a time, but the problem is that the thread access all the text areas and writes to them.

Coded in Java as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

class thread_action extends Thread
{
    private semaphores view;
    public thread_action(int threadNumber, semaphores view)
    {
        super(" " + threadNumber);
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void land()
    {
        //Try to land on Runway 1
        synchronized(view.output1) {
            view.output1.append("Plane" + getName() + " approach runway.\n");
            try { Thread.sleep (2500); }  
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) {}
            view.output1.append("Plane" + getName() + " descending ...\n");
            try { Thread.sleep (2500); }  
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { }
            view.output1.append("Plane" + getName() + " clearing runway and taxi to apron.\n\n");
        }
        //Landing completed 

        //Try to land on Runway 2
        synchronized(view.output2) {
            view.output2.append("Plane" + getName() + " approach runway.\n");
            try { Thread.sleep (1000); }  
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { }
            view.output2.append("Plane" + getName() + " descending ...\n");
            try { Thread.sleep (1000); }  
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { }
            view.output2.append("Plane" + getName() + " clearing runway and taxi to apron.\n\n");
        }
        //Landing completed

        //Try to land on Runway 3
        synchronized(view.output3) {
            view.output3.append("Plane" + getName() + " approach runway.\n");
            try { Thread.sleep (1000); }  
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { }
            view.output3.append("Plane" + getName() + " descending ...\n");
            try { Thread.sleep (1000); }  
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { }
            view.output3.append("Plane" + getName() + " clearing runway and taxi to apron.\n\n");
        }
        //Landing completed

        //Try to land on Runway 4
        synchronized(view.output4) {
            view.output4.append("Plane" + getName() + " approach runway.\n");
            try { Thread.sleep (1000); }  
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { }
            view.output4.append("Plane" + getName() + " descending ...\n");
            try { Thread.sleep (1000); }  
            catch ( InterruptedException e ) { }
            view.output4.append("Plane" + getName() + " clearing runway and taxi to apron.\n\n");
        }
        //Landing completed
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pickedNumber = rand.nextInt(10);
        int updateInterval = 1000*pickedNumber;
        try { Thread.sleep (updateInterval);  }  
        catch ( InterruptedException e ) {} 
        view.status.append("Plane:" + getName() + " has entered the airspace.\n");
        long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        land();
        long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long run_time = (end_time - start_time)/1000;
        view.status.append("\tPlane" + getName() + " took " + run_time +" seconds to land.\n");

    }
}

public class semaphores extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 700;
    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000;

    private Label labelOne, labelTwo, runway1, runway2, runway3, runway4;
    private TextField inputOne;
    private Button runButton, quitButton;
    public static TextArea status, output1, output2, output3, output4;

    public semaphores()
    {
        setTitle("Airport Simulation");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocation(10,20);
        setLayout(null);

        labelOne = new Label("Number of Airplanes:");
        labelOne.setBounds(5,17,140,40);
        add(labelOne);
        inputOne = new TextField();
        inputOne.setBounds(150,25,135,25);
        add(inputOne);
        inputOne.addActionListener(this);

        runButton = new Button("Run Program");
        runButton.setBounds(5,60,100,25);
        add(runButton);
        runButton.addActionListener(this);

        quitButton = new Button("Quit Program");
        quitButton.setBounds(150,60,100,25);
        add(quitButton);
        quitButton.addActionListener(this);

        labelTwo = new Label("Planes Status:");
        labelTwo.setBounds(300,20,140,20);
        add(labelTwo);
        status = new TextArea(10,40);
        status.setBounds(300,45,650, 180);
        add(status);

        runway1 = new Label("Runway 1:");
        runway1.setBounds(10,240,140,20);
        add(runway1);
        output1 = new TextArea(10,40);
        output1.setBounds(10,260,450, 200);
        add(output1);

        runway2 = new Label("Runway 2:");
        runway2.setBounds(500,240,140,20);
        add(runway2);
        output2 = new TextArea(10,40);
        output2.setBounds(500,260,450, 200);
        add(output2);

        runway3 = new Label("Runway 3:");
        runway3.setBounds(10,470,140,20);
        add(runway3);
        output3 = new TextArea(10,40);
        output3.setBounds(10,490,450, 200);
        add(output3);

        runway4 = new Label("Runway 4:");
        runway4.setBounds(500,470,140,20);
        add(runway4);
        output4 = new TextArea(10,40);
        output4.setBounds(500,490,450, 200);
        add(output4);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        int numThreads;
        String getInput;
        Button clickedButton = (Button) event.getSource();
        if(clickedButton == runButton)
        {
            status.setText(""); 
            output1.setText(""); 
            output2.setText(""); 
            output3.setText(""); 
            output4.setText(""); 
            getInput = inputOne.getText();
            numThreads = Integer.parseInt(getInput);
            thread_action[] threads = new thread_action[numThreads];
            for(int x=0; x<numThreads; x++)
            {
                threads[x] = new thread_action(x, this);
            }
            for(int x=0; x<numThreads; x++)
            {
                threads[x].start();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        semaphores threadObj = new semaphores();
        threadObj.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question in here?  I would suggest you really want to be looking at the examples of SwingWorker instead.  see http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html or even better http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you post some code, try to omit the non-relevant code (eg: Swing Init). This way you will become what they call an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I ran your code and I get Plane 1 approach runway.
Plane 1 descending ...
Plane 1 clearing runway and taxi to apron.

Plane 0 approach runway.
Plane 0 descending ...
Plane 0 clearing runway and taxi to apron.

Plane 2 approach runway.
Plane 2 descending ...
Plane 2 clearing runway and taxi to apron.
 for all 4 textboxes

Comment: I am trying to get a thread to choose another text area if one text area is already being used. If you use 4 threads, then each thread should only access one text area. I want the thread to test if it can access the object (view.output1) and if it cannot, then it must try view.output2, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The synchronized call does not mean "do this if runway 1 is available". It means "wait until runway 1 is available then do this".

For this you should use flags as well as the locks:

```
if (runway1available) {
    synchronized(runway1) {
        runway1available=false;
        landonrunway1()
        runway1available=true;
    }
}
else if (runway2available) {
   // ...
}
```

This way the other threads can see the flag is set and not try to acquire a lock. It would be more reliable to check the flag inside the critical section as well (double check locking), but there aren't significant consequences to leaving it out in this case.

You also need to be careful with your choice of lock objects - in most cases it is best to use a dedicated lock object that you know won't change or get accessed from another thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-) Added the flags to a Global class and it works.